# Placing advancements on non-advanceable cards

Tags: android-netrunner

I know you can't advance something that is non-advanceable, but what about the Runner?

In the new [Opening Moves Data Pack](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_news.asp?eidn=4134), there is a card called "Queen's Gambit" (according to the pics). It says:

> Place up to 3 advancement tokens on an unrezzed card in a remote server. Gain 2[Credits] for each advancement token placed.

Can anyone say that works? The Runner doesn't know what can be advanced or not..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Queen's gambit doesn't specify that the card has to be able to be advanced. If you compare it to Matrix Analyzer, you will see the difference:

> When the Runner encounters Matrix Analyzer, you may pay 1 [Credits] to place 1 advancement  token on a card that can be advanced.

Normally the Advance action is used to advance cards. This is where the corp pays 1C and 1click to place an advancement counter on a card which can be advanced. When another card places advancement counters, its not actually "advancing" the card, and so it doesn't need to be an advanceable card. However, most effects which add advancement counters specify the card has to be advanceable. The only exception at the moment is Queen's Gambit, since the runner obviously won't know, and is in fact gambling that the card *isn't* advanceable, to avoid helping the corp.

Comment: Seems like the right answer. Just seemed odd - I guess it's the first time a Runner advances a card, so they had to make the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Cards that require the target to be advancable say they must be. [Shipment from Kaguya](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01100) is an example from core, and [Trick of Light](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02033) is another one. Queen's gambit is meant to be a gamble, you are betting on the card you chose to not gain a benefit from the counters placed on it, if you're wrong you helped the corp out, if not, no issue. [Mushin no Shin](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05015) is an example of a corp card that advances cards without caring if they can be advanced or not.